# Traversing over nested parameters in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

Is there a way to traverse over parameters in rails?
I have a nested params:

```html
"request"=>{"name"=>"Gianni Hayes",
   "address"=>"5858 Bernhard Burgs",
   "phone"=>"(972) 399-9601",
   "mobile"=>"777 777 01 02",
   "filled_cartridges_attributes"=>{
      "0"=>{
         "cartridge_id"=>"HP laserjet 300",
         "_destroy"=>"false"}
          },
 "description"=>"sakld",
 "responsible"=>"15",
```

There might be many "filled_cartridges_attributes, so i need to iterate through them in controller.

Comment: the params object is basically just a (nested) hash, you can iterate over the elements like you would a normal hash. `hsh.each` etc.

Answer (score 0):

As params is basically a Hash. You can use [Hash#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-each):

```
params = "request"=>{"name"=>"Gianni Hayes",
   "address"=>"5858 Bernhard Burgs",
   "phone"=>"(972) 399-9601",
   "mobile"=>"777 777 01 02",
   "filled_cartridges_attributes"=>{
      "0"=>{
         "cartridge_id"=>"HP laserjet 300",
         "_destroy"=>"false"}
          },
 "description"=>"sakld",
 "responsible"=>"15"}
}
params["request"].each { |key, value| puts key.to_s + " : " + value.to_s }
# name : Gianni Hayes
# address : 5858 Bernhard Burgs
# phone : (972) 399-9601
# mobile : 777 777 01 02
# filled_cartridges_attributes : {"0"=>{"cartridge_id"=>"HP laserjet 300", "_destroy"=>"false"}}
# description : sakld
# responsible : 15
```

Or do it recursively as its hash of hashes:

```
 def deep_traverse(hash)
    hash.each do |key, val|
       puts key
       if val.is_a?(Hash)
         display val
       else
         puts val
       end
    end
 end
 deep_traverse params
 # request
 # Gianni Hayes
 # 5858 Bernhard Burgs
 # (972) 399-9601
 # 777 777 01 02
 # HP laserjet 300
 # false
 # sakld
 # 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, just as a hash. If you have following hash:

```
response = {"request"=>{"name"=>"Gianni Hayes",
                       "address"=>"5858 Bernhard Burgs",
                        "phone"=>"(972) 399-9601",
                        "mobile"=>"777 777 01 02",
                        "filled_cartridges_attributes"=>{
                              "0"=>{
                              "cartridge_id"=>"HP laserjet 300",
                              "_destroy"=>"false"}
                         },
                         "description"=>"sakld",
                         "responsible"=>"15"}
                       }
           }
```

Now here is the way to access `filled_cartridges_attributes`:

```
response["request"]["filled_cartridges_attributes"].each do |_, value|
  puts value["cartridge_id"] # => HP laserjet 300"
  ...
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`params[:request][:filled_cartridges_attributes]` will return a hash so you can iterate over it using `each` ,`each_value` or `each_key`
like:

`params[:request][:filled_cartridges_attributes].each_value {|value| p value}`